# Unable to download docker image layer from artifactory using JFrog CLI

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

Command:

```
jf rt download https://myartifactory/docker/myrepo/10.21.0/sha256__dd42811e-a483-5d86-8446-fec0d46f67d8
```

The command outputs:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "totals": {
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 0
  }
}
```

and in the logs I only see:

> [Info] Searching items to download...

Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The download command expects arguments to be a relative path so the command should have been:

```
jf rt download docker/myrepo/10.21.0/sha256__dd42811e-a483-5d86-8446-fec0d46f67d8
```